# Why can't put from stdin in memory assembler

Tags: assembly, console

I'm trying to edit some code.

I found a code in YT video, that printing "Hello World!" and it worked fine.

Then I decided to change it to modify the string from console, first fifth chars of it.
I found that "read" is 0x3 (eax) and stdin is 0 (ebx).
I added ;from ;to

```
global _start

section .text:

_start:

    ; from
    mov eax, 0x3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, message
    mov edx, 5
    int 0x80
    ; to

    mov eax, 0x4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, message
    mov edx, message_length
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 0x1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data:
    message: db "Hello World!", 0xA
    message_length equ $-message
```

nasm -f elf32 -o app.o app.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o app app.o
./app

There is reading from console, but the string isn't modifying, why?
And moreover than it, if I write more than 5 chars "qwertyui" - "yui" somehow... put in next command of console, after my app is closed!

Comment: Section names are not labels you must not use a colon. Change `section .data:` to `section .data` As it is, you defined a new section named `data:` (with a colon) which is not a standard section so it got default attributes which is read-only. As for the other question, yes, whatever you leave in the input buffer will be processed by the shell (or whatever reads next).

Comment: @Jester Thank you! So it was mistake in YT video...